# "Speaker Recognition and Segmentation"

Tags: java, c++, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speaker

Looking for a code that would process media file to "Who said what and when" in other words a "Speaker by speaker Segmentation" and what timing for each. Failing answers: doing any manual works to process the media file..thanks!

Comment: You didn't specify what language you're using.

Comment: Java...C++ will do as well..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use speaker diarization from Kaldi, it is not easy to setup but results are great.

There are many other libraries too - LIUM, bob, etc.

Comment: Thks Nikolay...with your background in this topic would LIUM fit for phone use explicitly for a mobile app....?

Comment: Not LIUM but you can create a similar implementation in C. That would fit.