# Getting Speaker labels or Splitting audio file that contains dialogue between two person?

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, audio-streaming

I have audio file that contains dialogue between two person I want to split audio file into two audio files that contains dialogue of both in separate file.
I am want to use this audio files further for Speech to Text.

Or

Getting Speaker labels about the dialogue spoken by each of them.

IBM provides Speaker labels but I want something other than IBM.

Is there any way of splitting the audio file according to speaker?

I want to do this through some API or program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Speaker Recognition and Segmentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457722/speaker-recognition-and-segmentation)

Comment: Can we implement LIUM in java?

Comment: Yes you can, it is already in java

Comment: Thanks I will try